# Need to restart Databricks 13.0 cluster to iterate on development

Tags: python, databricks, databricks-dbx

I want to iterate with development on a Databricks 13 cluster without the need to restart it for updating the code within my Python package.

It seems that **dbx execute** does the job on Databricks 12.1, but when I try to run it with Databricks 13, it gets the old version.

Also tried with

```
dbx deploy my_workflow --environment=dev --assets-only
dbx launch my_workflow --environment=dev --from-assets
```

without success.

Any ideas?

I've found the following issue with no definitive answer...

[How to reinstall same version of a wheel on Databricks without cluster restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73489698/how-to-reinstall-same-version-of-a-wheel-on-databricks-without-cluster-restart)

Thanks